# Android: push notification for my application which is not in android market

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I developed an application in android and i want to do push notification. I learned that this can be done by c2dm. Is there any way that i can test c2dm in my local system path of the app itself. can any body help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you wanting to know how to test your c2dm client side implementation [see here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#testing). You just need to install the google apis addon with your emulator and sign in to a google account.

If you had a different question please clarify and ill try to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You are very unclear, but judging by the title I guess you want to know if you can use C2DM for an application that exists just locally, and not in the Android Market, and the answer is: yes, you do not need to have your application published in the market in order for C2DM to work.